# Как отменить закрытие модального окна <dialog> при отправке формы (событии submit)

Tags: javascript, html, form, submit, dialog

При отправке формы (событии submit) внутри элемента `<dialog>`, этот самый dialog (модальное окно) автоматически закрывается.

```
<dialog>
    <form>
        <button>Отправить</button>
    </form>
</dialog>
```

Проблема решается сменой типа для кнопки формы:

```
<button type="button"></button>
```

Но в таком случае форма не будет отправляться.

Как сделать, чтобы модальное окно не закрывалось при отправке формы?

Comment: Делать отправку данных аяксом